# WP Rest API v2 return posts with specific tag

Tags: wp-query, filters, tags, json, rest-api

I am trying to get posts from blog: http://christianconcepts.com/ which are tagged "appcontent". I tried this querry:

`http://christianconcepts.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?filter[tag]=appcontent`

but it I still get unfiltered results. For example, this post: http://christianconcepts.com/pdf-ebook-available/ doesn't have "appcontent" tag but it is still returned.

"REST API - Filter Fields" plugin is installed.
Could someone help me?

Answer (score 8):

The filter param was removed in WP4.7, you should be able to access tags via their ID. For example to get the tag with the ID of 7 you could use:

```
http://YOUSIITE.DEV/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?tags=7
```

If you would like to add filters back in the WP-API team released their own Filter plugin, I'd recommend that you check that out: https://github.com/WP-API/rest-filter. From what I could see "REST API - Filter Fields" plugin actually restricts the content that is received from the API, it doesn't add Filter back in.

If you are adding the filter back in, remove the forward slash after `posts`, for example update:

```
http://christianconcepts.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?filter[tag]=appcontent
```

to

```
http://christianconcepts.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[tag]=appcontent
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: https://github.com/WP-API/rest-filter didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Is there any place in their documentation where they state *why* they removed searching by tag name in favor or tag ID?

Comment: There's was a discussion here: https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2799 as to why they removed the filter from the API. But to answer your question, it doesn't look like they've documented officially why they backtracked. Hope that helps.